# Messaging endpoint OAuth protection

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm trying to figure out if I need to perform anything special to my controller endpoint to secure the messaging endpoint.

At the moment I use a azure api with a app service to publish my bot, this bot has several endpoint because we need to call it from our SOAR solution.

I have secured the other endpoints using OAuth Azure Active Directory with the following code:

```
//Add Authentication and authorization
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
```

The problem I'm seeing at the moment is that identity model is complaining about the token that is received on the messaging endpoint because this is a bot token format and not azure ad (it's missing tid)

```
IDX40003: Neither `tid` nor `tenantId` claim is present in the token obtained from Microsoft identity platform.

IDX10233: ValidateAudience property on ValidationParameters is set to false. Exiting without validating the audience.
```

I got lost in numerous rabbit holes concerning bot framework and oauth

So basically my question is two fold:

- How can I fix these errors, or can I just ignore them?
- Is the messaging endpoint by default protected by the bot SDK or do I need to do something special in my code or on the API management page with jwt-validation

Best regards!

```
//Add Authentication and authorization
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
  .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

...


//Endpoint to receive messages from chat
[HttpPost("receivemessage")]
public async Task PostAsync()
{
   await _adapter.ProcessAsync(Request, Response, _bot);
}
```